# Palindrome checker - spacing

Tags: java, palindrome

I have a program where I am typing a Java program to check if the String entered is a palindrome. I have 2 problems going on that I can not for the life of me seem to figure out.

I have typed out the code so that it will tell me if it is a palindrome when all lowercase letters and no spaces involved. Any time I enter a palindrome with a space anywhere in it, it will tell me it is not a palindrome. Think I am just missing one little piece of code to make it work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word;
        String backwards = "";

        System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase and I'll tell you if it's a palindrome");
        word = keyboard.nextLine();

        int length = word.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            backwards = backwards + word.charAt(i);
        }

        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(backwards)) {
            System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That is not a palindrome!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work. Try doing "ab ba".

Comment: Alright, that did work..Other words that aren't perfectly even like ab ba don't work though..Was told to test the word Taco cat but it says that it is not a palindrome.

Comment: This is because "taco cat" does not equal "tac ocat". See my answer on how to disregard from spaces.

Comment: @np0212 Because it isn't. Reverse is "tac ocato". Did you want to remove spaces?

Comment: I did what aioobe said below and it was the remove spaces and it works now. Just looking at the example he still has the spaces in his code when it reads back to you but I believe this will be perfectly fine. Appreciate the help guys!

Comment: By the way, you can compact your code somewhat: 
`System.out.println(word + " is " + (word.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString()) ? "" : "not") + " a palindrome");`

Comment: Appreciate the help very much. Will read the article now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works as expected. (At least how *I* expect it to work; `"taco cat"` does not equal `"tac ocat"` so it should not be regarded as a palintrome.)

If you want to disregard from spaces, you could do

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

right after reading the input string.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to remove spaces from your strong. To do so, use the `replace()` method:

```
word.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: If OP wants to disregard from `" "` I bet he also wants to disregard from `"\t"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all spaces before performing the palindrome check.

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\s","");
```